# php help for online examination website

Tags: php

I am working on php to create an online examination website. I am almost done with the project, but stuck in a place. Let me tell you all first that I have 3 types of database defined:

1. for lower difficulty level of questions,
2. for moderate difficulty level of question, and
3. for higher difficulty level of question.

Now my project mentor wants a particular feature: i.e. if a student giving an exam answers consecutive 5 questions correctly, he should get the next set of 5 questions from the higher difficulty level database. If he answers 3 of the 5 consecutive questions correctly, he should get the next set of 5 questions from moderate difficulty level database.

I am still learning PHP, and don't have much knowledge about the language yet, so I would appreciate help with simple coding logic I can implement easily.

Comment: What part of that are you having difficulty with exactly? Doesn't sound all that hard to count the number of good answers. Please [edit] your post to add more specific details, including your attempt at solving this in PHP, so people can give you good advice/solutions. (Adding paragraphs wouldn't hurt either, your piece of text is hard to read.)

Comment: you have tried to do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is extremely vague and you have not provided the your tables information. Ideally, you need a single table (and single DB) for all your questions.

A sample structure would be:
id (auto increment)
difficulty (1, 2 or 3)
question 
answer

Then in PHP, first you show a random question by using a mysql query like

`select * from questions where difficulty = 1 order by RAND() limit 1`

After 5 correct answers (which you can store in php session information), you change the difficulty to 2 and so on.

I hope this helps.